Fetch last row for each month, or previous month if not found
I have a table balance_history that has the following structure and data (simplified)



Account
Balance
Transaction_date




a
100
29/09/2024


a
75
20/08/2024


a
65
18/08/2024


b
50
15/08/2024


c
200
10/07/2024



The balance of an account appears on that table only when there is a transaction. I can get the current/up-to-date balance of each account by running rank over partition statement for the entire table.
However, what I need is to show the monthly balance of each account. That means, if there was no transaction for a particular month, I want the query to search from the previous months and find the last transaction which has the latest balance (there is id column).
I want to show this outcome:



Month
Account
Balance




07/2024
a
0


07/2024
b
0


07/2024
c
200


08/2024
a
75


08/2024
b
50


08/2024
c
200


09/2024
a
100


09/2024
b
50


09/2024
c
200



As you see, even though there was no transaction for account c in September, I want to still show the balance. How can I can do this?

Aggregate the values by month and generate a calendar then use a PARTITIONed OUTER JOIN to join the monthly values to the calendar:
WITH month_data (account, month, balance) AS (
  SELECT account,
         TRUNC(transaction_date, 'MM'),
         MAX(balance) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY Transaction_date)
  FROM   table_name t
  GROUP BY
         account,
         TRUNC(transaction_date, 'MM')
),
calendar (month) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(min_month, LEVEL - 1)
  FROM   (
    SELECT MIN(month) AS min_month,
           MAX(month) AS max_month
    FROM   month_data
  )
  CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(min_month, LEVEL - 1) <= max_month
)
SELECT m.account,
       c.month,
       COALESCE(
         LAST_VALUE(m.balance) IGNORE NULLS
           OVER (PARTITION BY m.account ORDER BY c.month),
         0
       ) AS balance
FROM   calendar c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN month_data m
       PARTITION BY (m.account)
       ON c.month = m.month

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Account, Balance, Transaction_date) AS
SELECT 'a', 100, DATE '2024-09-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a',  75, DATE '2024-08-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a',  65, DATE '2024-08-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b',  50, DATE '2024-08-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 200, DATE '2024-07-10' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ACCOUNT
MONTH
BALANCE




a
2024-07-01 00:00:00
0


a
2024-08-01 00:00:00
75


a
2024-09-01 00:00:00
100


b
2024-07-01 00:00:00
0


b
2024-08-01 00:00:00
50


b
2024-09-01 00:00:00
50


c
2024-07-01 00:00:00
200


c
2024-08-01 00:00:00
200


c
2024-09-01 00:00:00
200



fiddle

@p3consulting It is the latest, that is what KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY Transaction_date) does.

@MT0, Thank you! this worked for me. But wow, a lot to unpack and learn from this query.

One option is to use recursive cte to prepare your data by creating rows for all the months you need, get last dates of the months and record last transaction date by the end of every particular month.
WITH    --  R e c u r s i v e    C T E : 
   months ( mnth, account, balance, tx_date, last_date_mnth, last_tx_date ) AS 
     ( Select 1, account, balance, tx_date, 
              LAST_DAY(To_Date( '01.' || Lpad('1', 2, '0') || '.' || EXTRACT(Year From Sysdate), 'dd.mm.yyyy' ) ),
              Max(Case When tx_date <= LAST_DAY(To_Date( '01.' || Lpad('1', 2, '0') || '.' || EXTRACT(Year From Sysdate), 'dd.mm.yyyy' ) )
                       Then tx_date
                  End) Over(Partition By account, 1 
                            Order By  tx_date
                            Rows Between Unbounded Preceding and Current Row)
       From   tbl
      UNION ALL
       Select mnth + 1, account, balance, tx_date,
              LAST_DAY( ADD_MONTHS(last_date_mnth, 1) ),
              Max(Case When tx_date <= LAST_DAY( ADD_MONTHS(last_date_mnth, 1) ) 
                       Then tx_date 
                  End) Over(Partition By account, mnth 
                            Order By tx_date
                            Rows Between Unbounded Preceding and Current Row)
       From   months
       Where  mnth < 12
     )

... with data colected for all the months you can fetch the last transaction's balance per month including previous month's balance if that is the last one ...
--    M a i n    S Q L : 
Select mnth_str "MONTH", account "ACCOUNT", Max(balance) "BALANCE"
FRom  ( Select  To_Char(last_date_mnth, 'mm/yyyy') mnth_str, account, 
                Case When Max(last_tx_date) Over(Partition By account, last_date_mnth) = tx_date 
                     Then balance 
                Else 0 
                End "BALANCE"
        From   months
        Where  mnth Between 7 and 9
  )
Group By mnth_str, account
Order By mnth_str, account

/*    R e s u l t : 
MONTH   ACCOUNT BALANCE
------- ------- -------
07/2024 a             0
07/2024 b             0
07/2024 c           200
08/2024 a            75
08/2024 b            50
08/2024 c           200
09/2024 a           100
09/2024 b            50
09/2024 c           200      */

NOTE:
To get all the data from the month of the first transaction till the current month please check the the code and the result in the fiddle here.
If there are balances less then zero in your actual data then (in the Select clause of the Main SQL) code for "BALANCE" column should be like here:
Nvl(Max(Case When balance != 0 Then balance End), 0) "BALANCE"


How would you show results from multiple years? This appears to only show results for the current year.

@MT0 It depends on period of interest. If that could be since the month of the first transaction untill the current month then like in the fiddle here -> https://dbfiddle.uk/yEDiM5DO

Hello This is my solution in Oracle 21c:
First i generate a unique combination of months and accounts, then a left join on the pairs of month-account combinations with the original data, selecting the latest balance using dense_rank per month and account.
The last select includes the case statement to calculate the total_balance based on whether the month of the transaction_date is the earliest for that account.
CREATE TABLE balance_history  (
    account VARCHAR2(10),   
    balance NUMBER,     
    transaction_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO balance_history (account, balance, transaction_date) VALUES ('a', 100, TO_DATE('2024-09-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO balance_history (account, balance, transaction_date) VALUES ('a', 75, TO_DATE('2024-08-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO balance_history (account, balance, transaction_date) VALUES ('a', 65, TO_DATE('2024-08-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO balance_history (account, balance, transaction_date) VALUES ('b', 50, TO_DATE('2024-08-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO balance_history (account, balance, transaction_date) VALUES ('c', 200, TO_DATE('2024-07-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));

    WITH monthly_account_pairs AS (
 select month, a.account from (
 SELECT unique TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS((select MIN(transaction_date) from balance_history), LEVEL - 1), 'YYYY-MM') AS month
    FROM balance_history
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= MONTHS_BETWEEN((select MAX(transaction_date) from balance_history), 
    (select MIN(transaction_date)from balance_history) )
    + 1)
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT account FROM balance_history) a
    ) , monthly_account_balances AS (
        SELECT 
            map.month, 
            map.account, 
            COALESCE(bh.balance, 0) AS balance, 
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(bh.transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM'), bh.account 
                ORDER BY bh.transaction_date DESC
            ) AS rank_order, 
            bh.transaction_date
        FROM monthly_account_pairs map 
        LEFT JOIN balance_history bh 
            ON map.month = TO_CHAR(bh.transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') 
            AND map.account = bh.account
    )
    SELECT 
        month,
        account,
        CASE 
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM COALESCE(transaction_date, TO_DATE(month || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))) <>
                (
                SELECT MIN(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM COALESCE(transaction_date, TO_DATE(month || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')))) 
                 FROM monthly_account_balances
                 )
            THEN MAX(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY COALESCE(transaction_date, TO_DATE(month || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')))
            ELSE balance
        END AS balance
    FROM monthly_account_balances mab
    WHERE rank_order = 1
    ORDER BY month, account;

Hope it helps.

This does not give a value for a month if there is no activity in that month - see fiddle where there is an extra row of input data and nothing is output for 2024-06.

@MT0 Thank you for this observation. You are right but i have corrected my initial query to show a month even if there is no activity in that month, in this case for the month of June. based on your data from the fiddle.
